# Populate sequence containing NaN

Tags: sequence, nan, nim-lang

Nim language question here. I want to read a series of floats from stdin (this example: 7, 1, 4, 4, nan, 4) and store it in a `seq[float]` type. The input may contain NaNs. But I fail to integrate such outliers.

My code:

```
var
  line: TaintedString
  timeSeries: seq[float]

while readline(stdin, line) != false:
  echo timeSeries
  timeSeries.add(parseFloat(line))
```

The output:

```
@[]
@[7.0]
@[7.0, 1.0]
@[7.0, 1.0, 4.0]
@[7.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0]
@[7.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, nan]
@[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

Facing the first NaN, Nim renders all inputs as NaNs. But I want this (last line of output):

```
@[7.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, nan, 4.0]
```

How do I solve it correctly in Nim? [Documentation](https://nim-lang.github.io/Nim/strutils.html#parseFloat%2Cstring) says NaNs are supported…

Comment: What platform are you on and what back-end compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using nim 0.19.4 on Linux/i386, backend compiler is gcc and I have the same effect with -d:release switch. Sorry, I omitted the import statement in above snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Since you echo `timeSeries` **before** you add the next number, the input of the last line with `4` causes the `@[7.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, nan]` and it is guesswork what you did after that to get the final output line. Although I doubt there is a valid reason for anything to set every value in the sequence to `NaN`, it might be that what your input triggered a bug.

I have not been able to reproduce your output
with your code (adding the required `import strutils`) when entering your sequence followed by another `4`, `nan` or empty line (the latter erroring on invalid float).

For easier testing, I put your input in a file `input.txt`:

```
7
1  
4
4
nan
4
```

and ran the following on the latest stable nim (Nim Compiler Version 0.19.4 [Linux: amd64]) as the latest devel nim (Nim Compiler Version 0.19.9 [Linux: amd64]):

```
import strutils

var
  line: TaintedString
  timeSeries: seq[float]

echo timeSeries
for line in "input.txt".lines:
  timeSeries.add(parseFloat(line.strip))
  echo timeSeries
```

(the `.strip` is only there to handle trailing spaces in the input that were a result of cut-and-paste and sloppy editing)

Both compilers output:

```
@[]
@[7.0]
@[7.0, 1.0]
@[7.0, 1.0, 4.0]
@[7.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0]
@[7.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, nan]
@[7.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, nan, 4.0]
```

compiling with `-d:release` did not cause any errors either.

Comment: I could reproduce your example, it works for me as well. I will investigate why it failed in my initial try (could not reproduce this quickly though)